# jQuery append string

Tags: jquery

Hello Stack Overflow i hope you are well today,

I have this code:

```
  $('.add_child').click(function(){
    var attrName = $(this).attr('name');
    var count = $(this).attr('count');
    $(this).attr('count', (parseInt(count)+1))
    var input = $('<input />');
    input.attr('type','text')
    input.attr('name',attrName+"["+count+"]" ) 
    $('.children_form').append('<li>'+[input]+'</li>');
})
```

i am trying to get my out to display as:

```
<li><input /></li>
```

But it doesn't seem to work properly i am getting this code in my HTML

```
<li>[object Object]</li>
```

I believe this line is giving me the issue:

```
$('.children_form').append('<li>'+[input]+'</li>');
```

Comment: What do you get if you remove the square brackes (`[` and `]`) from around the `input` in that final line?

Comment: @David Thomas the same as before <li>[object object]</li>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `[input]` you are creating an array. But `'<li>'+input+'</li>'` won't work either, because `input` is an object, not HTML.

You'd have to do like so:

```
$('.children_form').append($('<li />').append(input));
```

---

`count` is not a valid HTML attribute. You should use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead. You can set the initial value with an attribute in [*HTML5 data attributes*](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) format: `data-count="0"`.

Comment: Winner, Winner, Chicken Dinner !

Comment: @Xavier: I like that movie :)

Comment: was a great film, well Kevin was awsome in the film :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.add_child').click(function(){
    var attrName = $(this).attr('name'),
        count = $(this).attr('count');

    $(this).attr('count', (parseInt(count)+1));

    var input = $('<input />', {
        type: 'text',
        name: attrName + '[' + count + ']',
    });
    $('.children_form').append($('<li>').html(input));
});
```

Comment: @Felix, no sir. It accepts jQuery Objects too. You can try it by yourself.